# Where to place common functions in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am wondering where common functions should be placed in the express structure to be shared between different routes.

Is there any "best practice" for it?
Nothing is mention in the documentation about it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They should be placed in an include that you `require` from each route.

common.js

```
function Common(){}

Common.prototype.method1 = function(){}
Common.prototype.method2 = function(){}

module.exports = new Common();
```

route.js

```
var common = require('./common');
common.method1();
common.method2();
```

Comment: And where do you place the `common.js` file? Is there any recommended location for it?

Comment: Entirely up to you, just worth noting that `./common` expects it to be in the same directory as the route, so change this appropriately. May also want to use `__dirname` in place of `./`.